# Making a TicTacToe game; how can I get the tictactoe buttons to alternate between X and O?

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I just need to get it to alternate between "X" and "O" for the turns but it's only giving me X's.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
public class tictactoe {
    public static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 700;
    public static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;
    public static void main(String[] args)          
    {
        int slots = 9;

        final JButton[] gameButton = new JButton[9];

        JPanel ticTacToeBoard = new JPanel();
        ticTacToeBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        JButton clearButtons = new JButton("New Game");
        for (int i = 0; i < slots; i++)
        {
            gameButton[i] = new JButton();
            ticTacToeBoard.add(gameButton[i]);
            final int countTurns = i;

            gameButton[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Object clicked = e.getSource();
                    int turns = 1;
                    for (int p = 0; p < 9; p++)
                    {
                        if(clicked == gameButton[countTurns] && turns < 10)
                        {
                            if (!(turns % 2 == 0))
                            {
                                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("X");
                                turns++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("O");
                                turns++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            final int integerHack = i; 

            clearButtons.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    gameButton[integerHack].setText("");
                }
            });
        }
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setActionCommand("EXIT");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                if (cmd == "EXIT")
                {
                    System.exit(FRAME_WIDTH);
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel wonLabel = new JLabel();
        rightPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        rightPanel.add(wonLabel);
        rightPanel.add(clearButtons);
        rightPanel.add(exit);
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        mainFrame.add(ticTacToeBoard);
        mainFrame.add(rightPanel);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `actionPerformed` method. Every time a click happens, you set `turns` to 1. As a result, `!(turns % 2 == 0)` will always evaluate true, and you'll always draw an X.

Answer (score 0):

Just by quickly looking at your code, I would guess it is because your `turn` variable is local in all the `ActionListener` objects. Therefore, the `turn` variable is always 1 and you always run into the first if case. So the `turn` variable is always recreated on the stack as soon as you get a callback in the `actionPerformed` method. For a quick fix and test, try to put the turn variable in the `tictactoe` class and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is with the turns variable in your actionPerformed. If you want to keep a track of it you should move that out from your method.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as the other people have also said, you want "turns" to be initialized outside all your loops.

Secondly, I would like to point out a typo:

```
            if(clicked == gameButton[countTurns] && turns < 10)
```

should be

```
            if(clicked == gameButton[p] && turns < 10)
```

...unless you really want to change each button's text from X to O nine times each time a button is clicked.

But even fixing that typo is pointless. Why loop through to find a specific button when it doesn't matter which specific button it is? All the buttons have the same action handler, anyway, just nine separate copies of it, because you are creating nine identical copies each time around.

Instead, because all the buttons do the same thing, you should have one action handler for all the buttons.  If you're not sure how that's done, you create it outside your button making loop and assign it to a variable, and then you put in that variable when you assign each button's action handler, e.g.

```
 gameButton[i].addActionListener(myActionListener);
```